# Using third party library named "nsetools" for fetching stock data

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x

I want to make the code shorter.  Is there any way to loop through the `stocks` and `qty` dictionaries, access the closing prices of each individual stock and then calculate the current value of the investment preferably in one or two lines?

```
from nsetools import Nse
nse = Nse()

#stock name and buy price pair, but not used in my method below. I would  like a method that uses it though.
stocks = {
    "ADANIPORTS" : 284.95,
    "HINDALCO"   : 152.30,
    "ONGC"       : 279.70,
    "SBIN"       : 259.70
}

#stock name and quantity of stocks     
qty = {
    "ADANIPORTS" : 20,
    "HINDALCO"   : 20,
    "ONGC"       : 20,
    "SBIN"       : 20
}

### Adaniports
#Fetches a dictionary with data such as best buy/sell prices, 'closePrice', etc.
stock1      = nse.get_quote('ADANIPORTS')
#Accessing the 'closePrice' from the above dictionary. 
stock1Close = stock1['closePrice']

### Hindalco
stock2      = nse.get_quote('HINDALCO')
stock2Close = stock2['closePrice']

### ONGC
stock3      = nse.get_quote('ONGC')
stock3Close = stock3['closePrice']

### SBIN
stock4      = nse.get_quote('SBIN')
stock4Close = stock4['closePrice']

current_value = (stock1Close * qty['ADANIPORTS']) + (stock2Close * qty['HINDALCO']) + (stock3Close * qty['ONGC']) + (stock4Close * qty['SBIN'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never use `stocks`, so I removed it. It would also help if your `qty` actually had the exact same keys as you need for `nse.get_quote` (namely lowercase names), so I did that as well.

In addition, you can convert your whole code into one generator, which you can then sum over:

```
from nsetools import Nse
nse = Nse()

def get_closing(stock):
    return nse.get_quote(stock)['closePrice']

stock_qty = {"ADANIPORTS": 20, 
             "HINDALCO": 20,
             "ONGC": 20,
             "SBIN": 20 }

stock_gen = (get_closing(stock) * qty for stock, qty in stock_qty.items())
current_value = sum(stock_gen)
```

If you already have `stocks`, you could just do:

```
stocks = {
    "ADANIPORTS" : 284.95,
    "HINDALCO"   : 152.30,
    "ONGC"       : 279.70,
    "SBIN"       : 259.70
}

#stock name and quantity of stocks     
qty = {
    "ADANIPORTS" : 20,
    "HINDALCO"   : 20,
    "ONGC"       : 20,
    "SBIN"       : 20
}
current_value = sum(val * qty[stock] for stock, val in stocks.items())
```